# Why aren’t Koala and Scout apps opening?

Tags: css, sass, koala, scout-sass

I downloaded Koala for converting SASS to CSS. After download I open the software once and when I tried to opening it few minutes later it's not opening. I clicked it and it didn't response. After that I downloaded Scout App for same purpose and just like 1st time it opened for once and not responding anymore. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the thing, when koala is minimized it won't open again I don't know why but I've figured out a way to open it, go to task manager and end all koala background processes and then try open koala again...
Hope this will work for you too